# Как удалить элемент массива в питоне?

Tags: python

Почему не работает этот код?

```
for a in massiv:
    for b in massiv:
        if len(a)> len(b):
            del b
        elif len(a)<len(b):
            del a
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596463/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-for-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf)

Answer (score 4):

Код не работает, т.к. инструкция `del` не удаляет элемент, а уменьшает число ссылок на него на 1, `del a` означает, что нужно уменьшить число ссылок на элемент списка, на который ссылается `a`, но т.к. в списке остается ссылка на этот элемент, то он никуда не удаляется.

Answer (score 3):

Странная логика у вашего скрипта =). Но всеже.

Во время итерации по массивам в питоне не допускается удаление элементов. Для этого либо сделайте копию списка - massiv[:], либо итерируйте по старинке - по индексам. В случае индексов вы получаете доступ к элементам исходного массива.

```
massiv = ['12', '123', '1234']

for i in range(len(massiv) - 1):
    for j in range(len(massiv) - 1):
        if len(massiv[i]) > len(massiv[j]):
            del massiv[j]
        elif len(massiv[i]) < len(massiv[j]):
            del massiv[i]

print massiv # => ['1234']
```

Comment: 1- ваш код ведёт к IndexError для другого ввода 2- код у автора вопроса не удаляет элементы из массива (ни одного). См. [объяснение в ответе @l0ki](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/81685/23044) 4- это не рекомендуется, но можно удалять элементы во время итерации (достаточно просто в обратном порядке обходить список, см. [пример кода в конце моего ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596513/23044)) 3- алгоритм у вас кубический, что гораздо хуже [линейного решения: `lst[:] = [max(lst, key=len)]`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597054/23044)

Answer (score 2):

`maxlen= max([len(i) for i in massiv])
massiv=filter(lambda x: len(x)=maxlen, massiv)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in massiv:
    for b in massiv:
        if len(a)> len(b):
            massiv.remove(b)
        elif len(a)<len(b):
            massiv.remove(a)
```

Буковок больше, НО стало видно, что и откуда мы удаляем, и в целом это более правильный подход... а вообще, исходя из описания топикстартера, вообще не ясно ничего, кроме того, что у него что-то не работает...

P.S: пишите подробнее суть задачи и проблемы ;)

Comment: Рискованный код. .remove(a) удаляет первое вхождение a.

Comment: for a in massiv и выдаст первый встречный элемент.. риск нулевой если не допускать семнтических ошибок)))

Comment: `for a in massiv` -- перебор списка. Причём тут "первый встречный"? И первый, и второй, и третий. Просто при разных значениях massiv последовательность удалений будет весьма причудливой. Возможно правильной, но к человеку, который заставит меня в этом разбираться, я вряд ли буду относиться как к другу. Код -- удаление  всех элементов длиной меньше максимальной. Возможно работает, но ну его нафиг.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы удалить элемент из списка `lst`, если известен его индекс `i`:

```
del lst[i]
```

Чтобы удалить все элементы, кроме элемента с наибольшей длиной:

```
lst[:] = [max(lst, key=len)]
```

Идиоматический способ удалить элементы из списка, удовлетворяющие заданному условию, собрать элементы, которые следует оставить и заменить ими все элементы в списке:

```
lst[:] = [item for item in lst if keep(item)]
```

Comment: а почему не `lst[:] = filter(keep, lst)`

Comment: @AndrioSkur: если у вас уже есть функция, то можно `filter()` использовать, но чаще просто выражение есть типа: `if item and item[0]` -- в этом случае лучше list comprehension использовать вместо filter + lambda.

Answer (score -1):

- Во-первых, это кортеж или статический массив?
- Во-вторых, a и b - это не элементы, это просто моментальное представление.

Должно так быть:

```
for a in massiv:
    for b in massiv:
        if len(a)> len(b):
            del massiv[b]
        elif len(a)<len(b):
            del massiv[a]
```

Comment: Спасибо модераторам за то , что они неоформленную каку превращают в прекрасную конфетку

Comment: К сожалению код из примера неверен. a и b не являются индексами списка massiv

Comment: alexlz прав:  
если a или b не являются числами получим такую неприятность как:
  
Type Error: list indices must be int not string или какой там тип данных у вас.  
  
а если там будет все таки число ТО сразу получаем невозможность получить len(integer)  но даже если и получите каким-то неведомым образом вы удалите элемент по индексу, а не значению как предполагает задача топика.. при чем такой индекс может просто и не существовать в массиве от сюда получаем list index out of range  
  
читаем про изменяемые переменные в python

Answer (score -1):

Удаляем элемент:

```py
a = [1,3,5,7,4]
n = int(input())
a.pop(n)
print(*a, sep=" ")
```