# Как удалить элемент списка (list) если известна только его некоторая часть?

Tags: python

То есть у нас есть лист:

list = ['1', '2', 'some', 'sosoeye', 'sok', 'so talk about e' ]

как удалить элемент списка начинающийся на 's' и заканчивающийся на 'e'??

Comment: [пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597054/23044), как удалить элементы, которые критерию `keep()` не удовлетворяют.  Если не ясно как keep() для вашего случая написать, спрашивайте.

Comment: @jfs Благодарю, вы очень поможете если скажете как написать keep().

Comment: вы можете отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос задать: *"как определить, что строка начинается на 's'"* Потом если потребуется можно спросить *"как определить что строка заканчивается на 'e'"* Если и после этого не ясно будет как keep() написать, спрашивайте.