# Почему в новый список не добавляется элемент старого списка, отвечающий условиям

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список - `list`. Нужно на его базе сделать новый список - `list2`, в который не войдут элементы, начинающиеся на `s` и заканчивающиеся на `e`.

Написал код (добавлен ниже).

Почему в новый список попадают только элементы `'1'` и `'2'`, а `'sok'` не попадает. По условию он не должен попадать, если оба условия выполняются. У него одно условие выполняется, а другое не выполняется. Он же должен попадать в новый список?

```
list = ['1', '2', 'some', 'sosoeye', 'sok', 'so talk about e' ]
dlina = len(list)
list2 = []
for number in range(dlina):
    nitem = list[number]
    if nitem[0] != 's' and nitem[-1] != 'e':
        list2.append(nitem)

print(list2)
```

Результат работы программы: ['1', '2']

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как удалить элемент списка (list) если известна только его некоторая часть?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/779909/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша программа будет работать правильно, если написать во так:

```
lst = ['1', '2', 'some', 'sosoeye', 'sok', 'so talk aboiy e']
lst2 =[]
for i in lst:
    if i[0] != 's' or i[-1] != 'e':
        lst2.append(i)
print(lst2)
```

И вывод:

```
['1', '2', 'sok']
```

Это происходит потому, что операторы сравнения возвращают булевы значения, которые потом используются в операторе `and`, и таким образом в вашем коде операндами оператора `and` становятся `False` и `True`.

Answer (score 4):

Вот более идиоматическое решение использующее [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) с условием:

исходный список:

```
In [97]: lst = ['1', '2', 'some', 'sosoeye', 'sok', 'so talk about e' ]
```

решение:

```
In [98]: lst2 = [x for x in lst if not (x.startswith('s') and x.endswith('e'))]
```

результат:

```
In [99]: lst2
Out[99]: ['1', '2', 'sok']
```

Также можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
In [9]: import re

In [10]: lst2 = [x for x in lst if not (re.match(r'^s.*e$', x))]

In [11]: lst2
Out[11]: ['1', '2', 'sok']
```

[Разбор RegEx'а на английском...](https://regex101.com/r/iRShg0/1/)

---

PS не стоит использовать зарезервированные слова (например: `list`, `dict`, etc.) в качестве имен переменных, чтобы избежать неприятных эффектов:

```
In [1]: list = list('abc')

In [2]: list
Out[2]: ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [3]: list2 = list('xyz')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-02adb35530fa> in <module>()
----> 1 list2 = list('xyz')

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
if nitem[0] != 's' and nitem[-1] != 'e':
```

используйте

```
if nitem[0] != 's' or nitem[-1] != 'e':
```

(`or`  вместо `and`).

---

Вывод:

> `['1', '2', 'sok']`