# Как удалить все чётные элементы списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, список

Как удалить все чётные и нечётные элементы списка (нужны оба варианта) в Python 3.x? С чётными пробовал вот так:

```
a = [x for x in a if x%2]
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: код не может подобную ошибку выбросить. Если список у вас числа содержит (чтобы имело смысл о чётных/нечётных элементах говорить), то TypeError вы не получите, приведите реальный пример, который эту ошибку выдаёт.

Comment: Связанный вопрос (с заголовоком): [Как удалить элемент массива в питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597054/23044), [В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значит, у Вас массив *a* изначально содержит переменные типа *string*, стало быть нужно их переводить в *int* перед проверкой на четность.

```
a1 = [x for x in a if int(x)%2]     # Выбираем нечетные числа
a2 = [x for x in a if not int(x)%2] # Выбираем нечетные числа
```

Заметьте, что списки *a1* и *a2* будут также содержать переменные *строкового* типа.

А если Вам нужно хранить переменные *целочисленного* типа, нужно их преобразовать.

```
a1 = [int(x) for x in a if int(x)%2]
a2 = [int(x) for x in a if not int(x)%2]
```

Comment: a1 `# чётные | нужно исправить комментарий в 1м примере`

Answer (score 1):

Для выборки из списка элементов, удовлетворяющих какому-то условию, можно воспользоваться методом `filter`:

```
a = list(filter(lambda x: int(x) % 2, a))  // Оставляем только нечётные
a = list(filter(lambda x: not int(x) % 2, a))  // Оставляем только чётные
```

Comment: Я бы внёс правку но тут надо исправить только 4 символа( а на платформе доспустимо не менее 6) `точность соответствия определению чётности/нечётности числа` -- в комментариях явно не соответствие терминов

Answer (score 1):

Для эффективного решения подобных задач удобно воспользоваться модулем Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
```

создаем список случайных целых и преобразовываем его в строки:

```
In [110]: lst = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(20)).astype(str).tolist()

In [111]: lst
Out[111]:
['38',
 '55',
 '56',
 '25',
 '78',
 '10',
 '99',
 '68',
 '25',
 '16',
 '66',
 '88',
 '65',
 '57',
 '69',
 '40',
 '67',
 '58',
 '89',
 '2']
```

создаем `Numpy 1D array of integers`:

```
In [112]: a = np.array(lst).astype(int)

In [113]: a
Out[113]: array([38, 55, 56, 25, 78, 10, 99, 68, 25, 16, 66, 88, 65, 57, 69, 40, 67, 58, 89,  2])
```

выбираем четные элементы:

```
In [114]: a[a % 2 == 0]
Out[114]: array([38, 56, 78, 10, 68, 16, 66, 88, 40, 58,  2])
```

нечетные элементы:

```
In [115]: a[a % 2 != 0]
Out[115]: array([55, 25, 99, 25, 65, 57, 69, 67, 89])
```